# Bluetooth not discovering any device

Tags: bluetooth

Please check the status below

```
sumedh@sumedh-HP-Notebook:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; rfkill list all; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; uname -a
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804a]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:80cb]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b509 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
[    0.319733] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.324345] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[    0.325085] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[    0.478420] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[   10.987381] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[   13.473966] [drm] Found VCE firmware/feedback version 40.2.2 / 15!
[   13.662543] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   13.662583] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   13.662590] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   13.662594] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   13.662604] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   14.027422] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   14.043352] Bluetooth: hci0: ubuntu-0
[   14.043363] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   14.158613] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   14.158626] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   19.592992] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   19.593007] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   19.593016] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   19.992348] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   19.992354] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   19.992362] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   22.689532] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[  133.327316] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  143.599765] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  153.831252] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  164.098723] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  174.350315] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  277.475989] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  287.727475] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  298.000045] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  308.246433] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  318.497915] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  328.750432] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  339.001981] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  349.254323] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  359.505826] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  369.741321] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  380.014780] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  390.245344] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  400.497765] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  410.749235] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  420.999724] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  431.252183] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  441.503655] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  451.756140] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  461.991629] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  472.242118] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  482.494614] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  492.761082] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  503.013562] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  513.265077] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  523.532584] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  533.785020] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  544.036506] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  554.288027] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  564.541412] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  574.808914] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  585.059476] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  595.315889] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  605.563423] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  615.814827] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  626.050359] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  636.317856] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  646.569334] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  656.821758] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
[  667.074227] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 18
```

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2307649&p=13412980#post13412980